# How to calculate which grid squares a circle touches?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have an image consisting from roughly 4,000,000 pixels. Each pixel has a geographic XY-coordinate (the coordinate is located in the center of the pixel) and each pixel corresponds to a A x A meter square.

Lets say I drop a random point on to the image (with random XY-coordinates) and draw a circle of radius B meters around this point:

[image]

My question is: How  can I efficiently calculate which squares the circle touches?

Comment: P.S. a special case would also suffice, say A=8m and B=9m

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the Midpoint Circle Algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an effective function to determine whether circle intersects a square (also includes, also lies inside). This (Delphi implementation) doesn't use trigonometry ant square roots.
[image]

Note that this function is intended for single square. But this approach might be modified for square grid - you can evaluate horizontal shift value for the whole column once, and vertical shift value for the whole row once, then use calculated values     `SquaredDist = SqDistForRow[Row] + SqDistForColumn[Col]`

```
function IsCircleIntersectsSquare
            (CX, CY, CR: Integer; {circle}
             SX, SY, A: Integer{square}): Boolean;
var
  halfA, dx, dy, t, SquaredDist: Integer;
begin

  //halfsize
  halfA := A div 2;

  //distances to square center
  dx := CX - SX;
  dy := CY - SY;

  SquaredDist := 0;

  //square sides divide plane to 9 parts
  t := dx + halfA;
  if t < 0 then
    SquaredDist := t * t
  else begin
    t := dx - halfA;
    if t > 0 then
      SquaredDist := t * t
  end;

  t := dy + halfA;
  if t < 0 then
    SquaredDist := SquaredDist + t * t
  else begin
    t := dy - halfA;
    if t > 0 then
      SquaredDist := SquaredDist + t * t
  end;

  Result := SquaredDist <= CR * CR
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it! =)

Comment: Very useful for the physics simulations I'm writing! Does this algorithm have a name, or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: @a52 I saw similar approach some times, but don't think it has a name.

Comment: @MBo Truly Unique!